# DLL and Main Project Building - Annoyance

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a main executable project and a dll project in VS 2008.

*Sometimes* when I clean/rebuild the dll and then clean/rebuild the main project, the main project will not build because it says the dll is in use.

Closing both projects resolves the issue.

Why does this occur and how do I prevent it from happening?  It is annoying having to close and reopen the projects.

Error received when building main project after building dll:

> > Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxx\Desktop\abcdefg\x64\Release\abdcefg.dll': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Check the task manger to see if the app is still running

Comment: @Yassir - The app is not running.

Comment: From your description it sounds as though the two items aren't in one solution, which it sounds like they probably should  be.

Comment: @Peter LaComb Jr - Why?  There should be no such limitation in visual studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio locks output file on build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002273/visual-studio-locks-output-file-on-build)